# How can I use resharper refactoring to make an object that uses an object initalizer immutable?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a number of summary objects that look like this...

```
public class ObjectSummary : ISummary
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public string Name { get; set;}
     ...
     // other fields
}
```

With a usage case that looks like this:

```
public ISummary Summarize()
{
    return new ObjectSummary
    {
        Id = _id,
        Name = _name,
        ....
        // etc with other fields
    };
}
```

And I'm trying to refactor all instances like so (make them immutable):

```
public class ObjectSummary : ISummary
{
    public ObjectSummary(int id, string name,..., /* other params*/)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set;}
    // other fields
}

public ISummary Summarize()
{
    return new ObjectSummary(_id, _name,..., /*other params*/);
}
```

How can I refactor an object that uses an object initializer to make it immutable (also moving set logic from the object initializer into a constructor)?

Comment: I've been looking for something similar for some time, no luck yet.

Comment: This would be a great feature. In fact it would be nice to have the option to make a whole type immutable, i.e. make private members and properties readonly.